# Usage of personification of nouns

Tags: nouns

> 1)I will give to my wife a ring of gold.
>
> 2)I will give to my wife a gold ring.

Which is correct? If both are correct, what is the difference in meaning between them?

Comment: Both are 'correct', but no-one would talk about a 'ring of gold' in ordinary conversation, only (possibly) in poetry or formal literature.

Comment: @KateBunting what is the difference in meaning of these two sentences?

Comment: There isn't one, except what I told you in my first comment.